# How to make PyQt5 QScrollArea horizontal scrollbar show up dynamically?

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5, qscrollarea

I created a `QScrollArea` to show a directory tree and a file tree. When directories or files are shown in this area, the vertical scrollbar appears, but the horizontal scrollbar never works. This is the code (the actual code is very large, so I'm showing only relevant portions):

```
class SomeWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(QWidget, self).__init__(parent)

    def DirectoryOrFileSelection(self):
        layoutOne = QVBoxLayout()
        self.treeview_tabs = QTabWidget()
        self.directoryView = QScrollArea(widgetResizable=True) #QWidget()
        self.directoryView.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAsNeeded)
        self.filesView = QScrollArea(widgetResizable=True) #QWidget()
        self.filesView.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAsNeeded)
        self.treeview_tabs.addTab(self.directoryView, "Dirs")
        self.treeview_tabs.addTab(self.filesView, "Files")
        theHBoxLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        leftSpacing = 4
        theHBoxLayout.addWidget(self.treeview_tabs, leftSpacing)
        layoutOne.addLayout(theHBoxLayout)
        self.layout.addLayout(layoutOne)
```

This is what it looks like when there's no need for a scrollbar.
[image]

The vertical scrollbar promptly appears when I make the main window smaller.
[image]

However, when I expand one of the directories, even though the filenames go beyond the visible area, the horizontal scrollbar does not appear.
[image]

If I use `Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn` in place of `Qt.ScrollBarAsNeeded`, an inactive scrollbar shows up and never becomes active.
[image]

Could anyone help with how to make the horizontal scrollbar active when necessary? I need to be able to scroll horizontally to see the full filenames.

**UPDATE:** As per suggestions received, I applied the `setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy` directly to the `QTreeView`, but even though the scrollbar appears and looks like it's active, it does not seem to recognize when the content is going outside the view area. Shown in the image below.
[image]

Comment: QTreeView already is a scroll area (just like *all* Qt item views, which inherit from [QAbstractItemView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html)). Just add those widgets to the QTabWidget, instead of creating a new scroll area: as you can see in the last image, the two scroll bars are overlapping, meaning that they belong to different widgets.

Comment: Thank you. If you could post this as an answer with some sample code, I'd be happy to accept it after testing the working of the code.

Comment: I can't, as I've nothing to start with: in your code there's no trace of the views, and I based my comments on the images. If you provide an actual [mre] that includes the *actual* widgets that are added, then I could provide a revised version, but, frankly, I don't believe that's actually necessary: just remove those two scroll areas, and use `self.treeview_tabs.addTab()` with the views you were setting with `setWidget()` for the scroll areas.

Comment: I tried setting the `setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy` directly to the `QTreeView`, but although the scrollbar appears (as shown in the update in my question), it does not seem to recognize that filenames have gone beyond the viewable area. I assume this is a bug.

Comment: Definitely not a bug, it's the expected behavior: Qt item views are very complex, you need to get to know them more deeply to understand how they work. The last visible section of a QTreeView header is always stretched (see [`stretchLastSection()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html#stretchLastSection-prop)). Use `treeview.header().setStretchLastSection(False)` and eventually `treeview.header().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)` so that the scroll bar will only shown whenever necessary (assuming you're using the default `ScrollBarAsNeeded`).

Comment: I suggest you to take your time to read the documentation of *all* the classes you're using, including the inherited ones. In this case: [QTreeView](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreeview.html) > [QAbstractItemView](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html) > [QAbstractScrollArea](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractscrollarea.html) > [QFrame](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qframe.html) > [QWidget](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html) > [QObject](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html), as much as the related [QHeaderView](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html) (used for headers of QTreeView and QTableView).

Comment: Works. Thank you so much. It works with `Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn` too. Please do post this as an answer, and I'll accept it. I'm new to Qt, and am surprised to see so many nuances which should have been designed simpler than this.

Comment: item views are very complex widgets, you may think that your requirements are simple, but they are *your* requirements. Qt is an extremely extended framework (hundreds of classes, tens of thousands of functions) that allows deep and flexible customization, which obviously can make things look and seem less easy, especially to beginners. It's not designed to be "simple", it's designed to usable and extendable, and in that sense it's *very well designed*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to add the view to another scroll area, as all Qt item views are scroll areas.

Note that, unlike the headers of QTableView, the header of QTreeView automatically [*stretches* the last section](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html#stretchLastSection-prop):

> **Note:** The horizontal headers provided by QTreeView are configured with this property set to true, ensuring that the view does not waste any of the space assigned to it for its header. If this value is set to true, this property will override the resize mode set on the last section in the header.

This means that if you are only showing the first column of the tree, the names of files and directories will always be *elided* if their width exceeds the width of the widget, and the horizontal scroll bar will not be activated even if it's always shown.

```py
treeview.header().setStretchLastSection(False)
treeview.header().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
```