# pyqt5 QTreeView horizontal scrollbar doesn't show up again

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, scrollbar, qtreeview

I've this QtDesigner generated Widget : `mainuiXXXX.py`

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MyApp(object):
    def setupUi(self, MyApp):
        MyApp.setObjectName("MyApp")
        MyApp.resize(603, 413)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MyApp)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.treeView = QtWidgets.QTreeView(self.centralwidget)
        self.treeView.setObjectName("treeView")
        self.treeView.setHorizontalScrollMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.ScrollPerItem)  
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.treeView, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        MyApp.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MyApp)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 603, 29))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MyApp.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MyApp)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MyApp.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MyApp)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MyApp)

    def retranslateUi(self, MyApp):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MyApp.setWindowTitle(_translate("MyApp", "MyApp"))
```

and this MRE code :`test.py`

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QHeaderView

from PyQt5 import QtGui


from mainuiXXXX import Ui_MyApp


class MyApp(QMainWindow, Ui_MyApp):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyApp, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setupUi(self)

        self.model = None

        self.treeView.setHeaderHidden(True)


        self.treeView.header().setStretchLastSection(False)
        self.treeView.header().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)

        self.create_tree()

        print(self.treeView.header().stretchLastSection())

    def create_tree(self):

        self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()

        self.rootNode = self.model.invisibleRootItem()

        self.top = QtGui.QStandardItem('TOP')

        self.rootNode.appendRow(self.top)

        self.treeView.setModel(self.model)

        for i in range(100):

            self.mod = QtGui.QStandardItem(str('a'*i))

            # print(i)
            self.top.appendRow(self.mod)

            for i in range(3):
                self.mod2 = QtGui.QStandardItem(str(self.mod.text() + 'aaaabbb'*i))

                self.mod.appendRow(self.mod2)
                
                for i in range(3):
                    self.mod3 = QtGui.QStandardItem(str(self.mod.text() + 'aaaaccc'*i))

                    self.mod2.appendRow(self.mod3)

        self.treeView.expandAll()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyApp()
    myapp.show()

    try:
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
    except SystemExit:
        print('Closing Window...')
```

it includes the

```
self.treeView.header().setStretchLastSection(False)
self.treeView.header().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
```

from here: [pyqt5 QTreeView horizontal scrollbar doesn't show up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71812499/pyqt5-qtreeview-horizontal-scrollbar-doesnt-show-up) and [How to make PyQt5 QScrollArea horizontal scrollbar show up dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70891913/how-to-make-pyqt5-qscrollarea-horizontal-scrollbar-show-up-dynamically)

but no horizontal scrollBar again, its drivin me crazy, I get this:

[image]

Comment: Try setting the view's horizontal scroll mode to `ScrollPerPixel` in Designer.

Comment: Just deleted the entire line: self.treeView.setHorizontalScrollMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.ScrollPerItem)  ,didnt noticed it was there, it works fine now. Why this behaviour ? Is it a PyQt bug or QtDesigner bug or it is just as it should be ?

Comment: You should *never* manually edit pyuic files: as soon as you'll update the original UI in Designer that property will be reset again unless you set it in Designer as said above. That is an unwanted effect of having *single* column item views with the ScollPerItem mode: since it can only scroll between items, when you have only one column there would be no scrolling. I know it's not optimal (nor well documented), but that's how it works: when you only have one column (or row for vertical scroll) then you have to set the scrolling per pixel if you expect that items might exceed the view's size.